# hexadecimal converting back into decimal

Tags: hex

My book says the hexadecimal notation FFFF equals 65535 in decimal value. As I understand it that equals to 2^16.  There are a couple of things I still don't fully understand. 1) Is FFFF a mix of both hexadecimal and decimal notation? How does FFFF equals 2^16? I don't understand how to interpret FFFF.
 The right most F represents 8 4 2 1, the second most F represents 128 64 32 16, the third most F represents 2048 1024 512 256 the the left most F represents 32768 16834 8192 4096? Is that the correct way of thinking about FFFF? I'm not sure how FFFF equals 65535. I'm sorta lost I don't understand why FFFF equals 65535. Am i thinking about it correctly or am I way off?

Comment: FFFFb16 is 2^16-1. 10000b16 is 2^16. (65535 is obviously not a power of 2 since it's an odd number.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To begin with, `FFFF` does not represent 2^16, but rather 2^16 - 1 (it would not be possible for any power of two to be an odd number).

Much like the decimal digits represent quantities of increasing powers of 10, hex digits represent quantities of increasing powers of 16 (in each case, the number whose powers we are dealing in is called the *base* of the system). Let's break down and reconstruct decimal 65535:

```
6  5  5  3  5           /--> input is decimal: increasing powers of 10
|  |  |  |  |           |
|  |  |  |  \---> 5 * 10^0 = 5 * 1      =       5
|  |  |  \------> 3 * 10^1 = 3 * 10     =      30
|  |  \---------> 5 * 10^2 = 5 * 100    =     500
|  \------------> 5 * 10^3 = 5 * 1000   =    5000
\---------------> 6 * 10^4 = 6 * 10000  =   60000
                                          =======
                                            65535
```

The same with hex FFFF:

```
F  F  F  F               /--> input is hex: increasing powers of 16
|  |  |  |               |
|  |  |  \------> 15 * 16^0 = 15 * 1     =      15
|  |  \---------> 15 * 16^1 = 15 * 16    =     240
|  \------------> 15 * 16^2 = 15 * 256   =    3840
\---------------> 15 * 16^3 = 15 * 4096  =   61440
                                           =======
                                             65535
```

Comment: To OP: Keep in mind that `A` represents the decimal value `10`, `B` represents the value `11`, and so on. `F` is the biggest possible digit in hex

Comment: thanks a lot. Your answer has really helped me. The way your answer explains it it seems pretty strait forward. If you were converting FFFF into binary notation, what is the correct way of thinking about it? When converting to binary notation do you think of each F as a separate piece of do you think treat FFFF as one item?

Comment: @JessicaM.: Converting from base 16 to base 2 is much easier because 16 is a power of 2. This means that each hex digit corresponds to *exactly* 4 binary digits. 0 => 0000, 1 => 0001, 2 => 0010 ... F => 1111. So FF => 1111 1111 etc. So you basically treat each digit separately (because the stars are aligned and you can get away with it) and only need to know 16 conversions by heart to instantly convert any number. Even if you don't know them by heart it's easy to deal with such small numbers in your head.

Comment: @JessicaM. - The nice thing about hexidecimal is that since it's base 16, which is a power of 2, it's easy to convert to Binary. Base 8 (octal) is another common power-of-2 base with an easy conversion. When you convert to binary, you _can_ think of FFFF as a whole number, but it's easier to just convert each digit individually and then put them all together.

Answer (score 1):

F is 15 in hexadecimal.  So,

```
FFFF = 15*16^3 + 15*16^2 + 15*16^1 + 15*16^0
     = 65535
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check your correct interpretation step by step with `bc` on any Unix platform.

Type:

```
bc
ibase=16

F
15

F0
240

F00
3840

F000
61440

F000+F00+F0+F
65535

ibase=A
2^16 - 1
65535
```

<kbd>^ ctl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>